# Append the publication name after every Page Title in SDL tridion

Tags: 2011, 2013, cme

I need to implement a code that appends text to the published page's title.

The appended text is different based on the publication that the page is published from, with the actual text to append (e.g. UK,Spain,France etc.) being maintained within a Keyword in Tridion.

For example, if my page is about a 'Paper dispenser', then browser tab (i.e. the HTML `title` element) should display the page title: "Paper dispenser | Tork Spain" - where 'Spain' is the publication specific part (maintained in the Keyword) and 'Tork' is a set piece of text that should be appended too.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming I understood you correctly and you wish to output this in the title of on each page on your website...

I would not recommend actually changing the Page names -- even if automated, it will be a mess to maintain. Instead, it's something you should do in your Page Template(s). Just output the correct text in the `<title>...</title>` tag of the HTML output.

If the Publication name has to come from a Keyword, as you suggested, I would create a Metadata Schema with a Keyword field and assign it to each Publication. Users can then choose the correct Keyword to use for all Pages in that Publication.

Your Page Template can then read the selected Keyword and output the correct prefixes. This way, it's trivial to change what gets appended to all Pages at once.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite vague and it seems you are unknowingly mixing a lots of things - things on CMS side and things on CD side. Assuming you are taking to achieve this page functionality on the Rendered Page on the browser and can do following:

You can have a metadata schema which is having field for Country/Publication Name coming from the Cateogry-Keywords as well as for your Project (I guess Tork is your specific project). You can then read this information for each page if you want this information to be different for each page.

If you have this information to be constant for all pages with in a Structure Group, apply this metadata schema on a Structure Group and read this information from there for each page with in the SG.

If you want this information to be constant for each page with in a publication, you may need to have this metadata information applied on the Publication and you could read it from there for each page with in the publication and so on...

Now, how to read this information really depends on a variety of factors like what is your business context, what templating/Framework you are using (DWT, Razor, DD4T etc.) etc.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

it is not clear where you want to implement the code, I am assuming you want to update the title in the tab(page title) in the browser while opening a tridion page in CME.

Simply you need to do this:

1. Create a gui extension extending resource "Tridion.Cme.Views.Page", please read this [link](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-BC8E7D93-73E5-45AF-BD11-D8B41FC48A53)
2. in the initialize function of the extension Update the title of the page.

Comment: One catch with a GUI extension for this on the Page form view is that shared pages in say a "Master" Publication wouldn't have a language. This would only show for the (often) read-only versions in child Publications.

Comment: I assumed he was talking about actual pages on the website, not within the CME. Since it should already be clear which Publication you are in, when in the CME.

Comment: Yeah, I'm leaning towards `title` in webpages, though "Page Title in SDL Tridion" confuses me a bit. Indeed in the CME, we can see the Publication in the breadcrumb in the list and form view and "from Publication" makes it clear across Publications.